# StencilJS export custom class

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

Is there any way to force StencilJS to export enums in order to be used by regular JavaScript code?

Generated JavaScript file exports the component classes only.

```
export { Calendar, CalendarDailyView, CalendarMonthlyView, CalendarWeeklyView, CalendarYearlyView };
```

It does not export other classes or Enums defined using JavaScript.

let's say an Enum is defined in TypeScript as follows:

```
export enum ViewType {
    daily = 0,
    weekly = 1,
    monthly = 2,
    yearly = 3
}
```

the generated JavaScript file contains:

```
var ViewType;
(function (ViewType) {
    ViewType[ViewType["daily"] = 0] = "daily";
    ViewType[ViewType["weekly"] = 1] = "weekly";
    ViewType[ViewType["monthly"] = 2] = "monthly";
    ViewType[ViewType["yearly"] = 3] = "yearly";
})(ViewType || (ViewType = {}));
```

how to force StencilJS to add ViewType to the exported types list?

Answer (score 3):

`Enum` is entirely a TypeScript concept. JavaScript has no concept of Enums, and the generated code you see is the 'best' solution that TypeScript can generate, [given all of the functionality TypeScript Enums have](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

To make it compatible with plain old JavaScript it might be worth declaring `ViewType` as a basic array, e.g.

```
export const ViewType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Day' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Month' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Year' }
];
```

Much easier to interpret in JS than the compiled TypeScript, and a better solution if you're going to be rendering any of these data to the screen.

To make this answer Stencily, here's my example in use:

**list-items.ts**

```
export const ListItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Day' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Month' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Year' }
];
```

**my-dropdown.tsx**

```
import { Component, State } from '@stencil/core';
import { ListItems } from './list-items';

@Component({
    tag: 'my-dropdown'
})
export class MyDropdown {

    @State() state: { selectedId?: number } = {};

    private onSelectedValueChanged(evt: UIEvent) {
        this.state = { ...this.state, selectedId: parseInt((evt.target as HTMLInputElement).value) };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.onSelectedValueChanged.bind(this)}>
                    <option>Please select...</option>
                    {ListItems.map(i => <option value={i.id}>{i.name}</option>)}
                </select>
                <br />Selected ID: {this.state.selectedId}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Important**: To reuse your exported collection or enum in other applications, be sure to build as `dist` (see [outputTargets documentation](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config/#outputTargets) in your `stencil.config.js`.

In this example, building as `dist` will include the separate export in `/dist/collection/my-dropdown/list-items.js` so that it can be re-used in other dependent apps and libraries.

Comment: Thank you. I know there is nothing called enum in Javascript. The question is how to force StencilJS compiler to export the generated classes or objects to be used by regular Javascript. StencilJS compiler exports the components classes only nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If I understand correctly, you want to expose your enum (however you define it) alongside your web component? All types are exported your `outputTarget` is `'dist'`, but not exposed for outputTarget type `'www'`. I'll update my answer.